# How can i transform this dataframe into this required design?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table like the folliwing:

[image]

I have to compare personA and PersonB, it is quite hard to judge by eye if personA has spent less or more than personB, Therefore i'd like to dynamically (using pandas) add a column for each amount_spent attribute where IF personA spends less than person B for that category then put Y... i am unsure how to achieve the below in pandas:

[image]

can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column name structure is same,You can use `np.where` like this:

```
x=['food','clothes','vehicles','gadgets']
for i in x:
    df['amount_spend_'+i+'_tag']=np.where(df['amount_spend_'+i+'_PersonA']<df['amount_spend_'+i+'_PersonB'],"Y","")
```

Comment: But that means i have to repeat the lines i.e. hardcode alot isn't there some sort of regex i can use?